# Avoid re-writing constructors of derived classes?

Tags: c#, oop

I have 3 (not counting service classes) C# classes and their constructors that are written in the way to use **Dependency Injection** (I am using **Microsoft Unity** DI framework) as follows:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public ServiceClass1 Sc1 {get;set;}
    public ServiceClass2 Sc2 {get; set;}

    public BaseClass(
           ServiceClass1 sc1,
           ServiceClass2 sc2
    )
    {
       Sc1 = sc1;
       Sc2 = sc2;

       // assign C# Session value to property UserEmail for all Service classes that are passed in the Base class contructor
      SC1.UserEmail = (string) Session["UserEmail"];
      SC2.UserEmail = (string) Session["UserEmail"];
    }


}

public class DerivedClass1: BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass1 (
           ServiceClass1 sc1,
           ServiceClass2 sc2
    ): base(sc1, sc2)
    {

    }
}

public class DerivedClass2: BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass2 (
           ServiceClass1 sc1,
           ServiceClass2 sc2
    ): base(sc1, sc2)
    {

    }
}
```

The problem is  whenever there is a new Service class that is used, it must be added to the constructor parameter list of the Base class and and the constructor parameter list of the Derived classes need to be updated so that the property UserName of the new Service class is assigned as other prior Service classes. Also a new Service class typed property must be added to the Base class (I know I cannot avoid adding such a new Service class property the Base class). I have to re-write the Base and Re classes' constructors as follows

```
public class BaseClass
    {
        public ServiceClass1 Sc1 {get;set;}
        public ServiceClass2 Sc2 {get; set;}
        public ServiceClass3 Sc3 {get; set;} // added property

        public BaseClass(
               ServiceClass1 sc1,
               ServiceClass2 sc2,
               ServiceClass3 sc3 // added constructor parameter
        )
        {
           Sc1 = sc1;
           Sc2 = sc2;
           Sc3 = sc3; // added code line

           // assign C# Session value to property UserEmail for all Service classes that are passed in the Base class contructor
          SC1.UserEmail = (string) Session["UserEmail"];
          SC2.UserEmail = (string) Session["UserEmail"];
          Sc3.UserEmail = (string) Session["UserEmail"]; // added code line
        }


    }

    public class DerivedClass1: BaseClass
    {
        public DerivedClass1 (
               ServiceClass1 sc1,
               ServiceClass2 sc2,
               ServiceClass3 sc3 // added parameter
        ): base(sc1, sc2, sc3) // re-write passing arguments
        {

        }
    }

    public class DerivedClass2: BaseClass
    {
        public DerivedClass2 (
               ServiceClass1 sc1,
               ServiceClass2 sc2,
               ServiceClass3 sc3 // added parameter
        ): base(sc1, sc2, sc3) // re-write passing arguments
        {

        }
    }
```

**My question: how can I avoid modifying constructors of Derived classes whenever there is new Service class added to the Base class' constructor?**

Comment: You could define a superservice containing all your services, so you'll only ever need to pass the instance of the superservice. Don't forget to register the superservice, too.

Comment: [This post](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) has a great explanation/example of a way to handle this (similar to what @Vlad mentioned with the superservice)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this is to don't use the constructor to define your dependencies. Some Dependency Injection Frameworks like AutoFac support [property injection](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html).

That way you don't need the constructor to set the dependencies, but instead the Dependency Injection Framework takes care of setting the dependency properties for you.

The disadvantage of this is, that if you create your instance without the Dependency Injection Framework or you don't to initialize property injection, then you "have to know", that you must set the dependency properties, because there is non constructor that forces you to set them.

Comment: Unity DI seems to support [Property Injection](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/ioc/property-injection-using-unity-container)